# Stopwords on a DataFrame Column

Tags: python, pandas, stop-words

I'm cleaning a excel file so I could present it on PowerBi. 
I want to eliminate the Stopwords of a specific column, and this is the code I'm using but it appears a problem. The stopwords I need to eliminate are at spanish.

Also I'm replacing the . and , to spaces to split the column and analize the information, if you know a easier way please let me know.

```
import nlkt
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop = stopwords.words('spanish')
df['Producto'] = df['Producto'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in (stop)]))

df["Producto"] = df["Producto"].str.replace(",","")
df["Producto"] = df["Producto"].str.replace(".","")

df = df["Producto"].str.split(" ", expand = True)
print (df)
```

Comment: please show an example of your dataframe and your expected output

Comment: I think you should update your question

Comment: Regarding your [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59493199/4076315), you need to click the [edit] link under your question to updated it. You should also add your example data as text (you can use code formatting to make column spacing easier), not as a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And Rahul P already help me with what I need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fast way to do it. I recreated a dataframe with some sample data:

```
import re
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + r'|'.join(stopwords.words('spanish')) + r')\b\s*')
df_temp = pd.DataFrame({'Words': ["Uno", "Dos", "Tres", "Other", "los"]})
df_temp['Words'] = df_temp['Words'].map(lambda x: pattern.sub('', str(x)))
```

Output of df_temp:

```
Words
0   Uno
1   Dos
2   Tres
3   Other
4
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your help, it appear a problem                                     
df['Producto'] = df['Producto'].map(lambda x: pattern.sub('', x))

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: It is probably because you have integers or (possibly?) blank values. Do you have non string values in that column?

Comment: Yeah I had blank values and integers, how I could do it? Because I use this df["Producto"] = df["Producto"].str.replace(",","") but it seem it do not work

Comment: Just updated my answer. I cast x to str(x) in the lambda function and it seems to work. Try it and let me know.